# Problem reading an XML file in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml, xmlreader

I'm using a simple XmlReader on the following file structure:

```
<application>
    <nodetitle permission="perm1">Some Dept</nodetitle>
    <project>Project A</project>
    <links>
        <link>
            <pagename>page1.aspx</pagename>
        </link>
        <link>
            <pagename permission="perm2">page2.aspx</pagename>
        </link>
        <link>
            <pagename>page3.aspx</pagename>
        </link>
    </links>
</application>
```

I'm rusty on the XML API and my problem is reading the sibling <link> elements in a single pass - my instinct is to look to create some kind of inner loop?

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    ...

    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "links"))
    {
        // read all <link> elements in a single pass
    }
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE - 06-25-2011**

I'm going to try and be a little more specific. I'm not using XPath. Using either the XmlReader **or Linq to Xml** (am totally unfamiliar with this), I want a way to extract the link elements and attributes and check their values.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to just use xpath to select the nodes you want? Using an XmlReader seems much more difficult.

Comment: I guess not, just never used it before. I want to be able to extract all info (atts & values) for each link before moving on to the next iteration of the main while loop - would welcome a code sample :)

Comment: I had a look at Api and found method to read subtree, method is reader.ReadSubtree. It returns you an instance of XmlReader object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you use an XML doc you could do something like this:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument
    .DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//application/links/link");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
    ...
}
```

In the loop just get the inner `<pageName>` element and read the attributes and/or text.

That said, XPath is much easier, faster and memory efficient than a reader or a full Xml doc. Linq2XML is also really good to work with, since you can use Linq syntax on the parse tree.

**Edit:**

I felt kind of dirty for mentioning XmlDocument so I created a simple Linq2Xml example to show how easy this is even omitting any Linq syntax, just in case you want to go for it:

```
string path = @"C:\path\to\my\xmlfile.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.None);

var nodes = doc.Root.Element("links").Elements("link");
foreach (var node in nodes) {
    var pageNameElement = node.Element("pagename");
    XAttribute permAttribute = pageNameElement.Attribute("permission");
    string permission = "";
    if (permAttribute != null)
        permission = permAttribute.Value;
    string text = pageNameElement.Value;
    // Do something with the values...
}
```

You can of course initialize the XDocument with a stream, if that's what you already have. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Working through this now, feel free to offer any Linq syntax :)

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to XML makes this stuff crazy easy sauce:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("xml here or use .Load()");
var links = doc.Descendants("link");
```

You can extend off from here reading attributes (XAttribute) off the XNode individually or again using LINQ to obtain all of the attributes for all nodes etc etc.

Comment: Have never used LINQ to XML, is it possible to query without using an XDocument? Looking for a link relevant to this scenario...

Comment: You can start at the XNode level using the static XNode.ReadFrom method which takes your XmlReader as a param and returns the XML fragment as an XNode.  If you don't have it already I'd highly recommend downloading LINQPAD (http://www.linqpad.com), loading in your XML and exploring the API.

Comment: Daz, can you give me the syntax or a doc link, for digging into the elements and attributes? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Although i wouldnt prefer XmlReader over LINQ or XmlDocument,
this should help u working with xmlReader(scroll down)
http://vbdotnetforum.com/index.php?/topic/493-creating-an-xml-reader/

--

U might want to use LINQ, it shouldnt be hard to understand.. Here is a starter
http://www.developingfor.net/c-30/upgrade-your-c-skills-part-5-linq-to-xml.html